# Disable Screwdriver in Visual Studio 2017 15.7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

After installing 15.7 I noticed there's a new screwdriver icon in addition to the present lightbulb. I would like to disable the screwdriver or make it not appear for the default case "Generate Overrides". I find it distracting it's following me on empty lines. If I wanted the overrides I would start typing "over.." and Intellisense would take care of the rest. I do not want to disable Lightbulb or Intellisense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Quick Actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions) can be applied by using the light bulb light bulb icon or screwdriver screwdriver icon icons, or by pressing Ctrl+.

The icon that appears when a Quick Action is available gives an indication of the type of fix or refactoring that's available. The screwdriver icon indicates just that there are actions available to change the code, but you shouldn't necessarily use them. The yellow light bulb icon indicates there are actions available that you should do to improve your code.

Now there is no such setting to disable the screwdriver, and I found some others shared this suggestion to the Product Team, please check [this](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/34277428-don-t-show-screwdriver-icon-at-all-if-a-user-wan) and you can vote it to make the Product Team engineers notice this user voice.

Comment: I just want to verify that there truly is no way to disable the lightbulb and screwdriver popups. If not, I'm rolling back to VS 2013. The inability to turn this garbage off seems just too insane to be believable so want to verify.

Comment: Yeah, every time I upgrade to a new VS version I have to figure a way to get rid of all the judgmental doohickies that tell me I'm a bad programmer. Very frustrating. And don't get me started on the auto-complete features that believe I can't type for myself.